# Dynamic file name in directory

Tags: python-3.x

I am able to write file in directory using python with following code.
How can I pass the dynamic file name in below code. Right now i am passing hard coded name -'abc.xml'. I have a for loop and file name will be different for each loop iteration. How can i open the directory and then write each file with different file name in it?

```
import os
if not os.path.exists(directory):
      os.makedirs(directory)

with open(directory +"\\"+'abc.xml', 'wb') as file:
     file.write(a.content)
```

Comment: Are the all those files are located inside a single folder/directory? or each file located in different directory?

Comment: I am writing to the directory and in each loop directory and file name changes. I am hitting an API and then create folder and then write the content of api with appropriate file name.

Comment: Okay then answer given by @Zaven Zareyan should work for you i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting file name:

```
import os
if not os.path.exists(directory):
      os.makedirs(directory)

for i in range(10):
    with open(directory + "\\" + f'abc_{i}.xml', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(a.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way to get the filename as an argument is by using argv

sys.argv[0] - is the script name - python
sys.argv[1] - is the first argument to the scripts

so you can do the following:

```
with open(directory +"\\"+sys.argv[1] , 'wb') as file:
     file.write(a.content)
```